Relative position of a straight line and a circle: is there a proof without Pythagoras theorem?
Consider a line and a circle on the same plane.
Preliminaries
A slope from a given point to a given line is a segment that is not perpendicular to that line and that connects the given point with a point on a given line.
A circle is defined as a shape consisting of all points in a plane that are at a given distance from a given point called this circle's center.
It is a common knowledge that there are three possible relative positions of a straight line and a circle:


Exterior of a circle, if a line has no (zero) common points with a circle.



Tangent of a circle, if a line has one common point with a circle. This point is also referenced to as a point of tangency.



Secant of a circle, if a line has two common points with a circle.

This list is exhaustive, because a straight line cannot have more than two common points with a circle. The reason why it's true was previously discussed in this question.
The Theorem
The question is about the following theorem which provides the means to determine the amount of intersection points of a plane and a circle:

It is possible to determine the relative position of a given line and a given circle by comparing the radius $r$ of that circle with the distance $d$ to that line from that circle's center.

If $d > r$, then the given line is exterior of a given circle.
If $d = r$, then the given line is tangent of a given circle.
If $d < r$, then the given line is secant of a given circle.


I will provide a purely geometric proof that I know.
Consider a circle $\omega$ with radius $r$ and point $O$ being its center; let $OH$ be the distance $d$ from $O$ to the given line $l$. Let's consider three possible cases:

$(d < r)$. In this case, construct such segment $AB$ on line $l$ that $AH = HB$, and $|AB| = 2\sqrt{r^2-d^2}$. Then, $|AH| = |HB| = \sqrt{r^2-d^2}$.
Consider triangles $_\Delta OAH$ and $_\Delta OBH$. These are right triangles with common leg $OH$ and equal legs $AH$ and $BH$ (by construction). Therefore, these triangles are congruent by LL, and from that, we conclude that $OA=OB$.
By Pythagorean theorem, $OA = \sqrt{OH^2+HA^2} = \sqrt{d^2+(r^2-d^2)} = r$. Therefore, $OB = OA = r$. Therefore, points $A$ and $B$ are on a circle $\omega$ by definition (provided in Preliminaries), and that finishes the proof for this case.

$(d = r)$. In this case, $OH=r$, therefore $H$ is on a circle. Any slope from point $O$ to line $l$ is longer than perpendicular $OH = r$, therefore line $l$ has no other common points with a circle, and that finishes the proof for this case.

$(d > r)$. In this case, $OH>r$. Again, any slope from point $O$ to line $l$ is longer than perpendicular $OH > r$, so there is no point $P$ on line $l$ such that $OP=r$. It follows that line $l$ has no common points with a circle, and that finishes the proof for this case.


The Question
I would like to have a geometric (non-trigonometric, and non-coordinate) proof of the same theorem that will be independent of Pythagoras theorem. This is important for me to know such proof or its impossibility with the given restrictions to check my intuition that hints me that such proof indeed exists.
Such intuition is based on the following thought: if perpendicular from a circle's center to a given line is shorter than the radius of a given circle, then the base of this perpendicular is certainly inside the circle, therefore since circle cuts a closed region of a plane, that line should 'enter' and 'exit' that region at some points, which are these two points this line intersects that circle with.
But that's by no means a geometric proof. It's just a mere observation, and I'm looking to somehow transform it to the actual proof.

One way to avoid Phytagoras is to study when there are two tangents to the circle, when there is only one, and when there are none.

Why not GEOMETRICLY draw the vertical from O to the line. And evaluation of the intersection with the circle? What you mean by geometric?

@Piquito Can you provide such thing as an answer? Intuitively, a circle has one tangent from a point when it is on a circle, two tangents when it's outside of a circle, and no tangents when it's inside the circle.

@Moti By 'geometric proof' I do mean Euclidean-style proof.

If the shortest distance to the line is less than the line then the point on the line nearest the center is in the interior of the circle.  So the line has a point interior to the circle. Only the case were the line intersects at two points allows for this.  Same for other two cases.

@Rusurano: I wanted to give an answer but  but having thought of an equilateral triangle I put isosceles and acted with such a triangle which conditioned a wrong answer. I am old and should already leave MSE but the temptation to continue persists.

@Piquito it happens, no worries! :)

@Rusurano: Anyway with triangle $ABM$ equilateral  $d=r$ is correct,, $d\gt r$ incorrect and $d\lt r$ correct. But I could repair this if i would wanted to. Regards. (in particular the proof of $d=r$ with an equilateral triangle and without Phytagoras is nice.

Presumably it has been already proven that given a line, $L$, and a point, $p$, not on the line that there exists a unique perpendicular line to $L$ containing $p$ and that distance of $p$ to the point where the perpendicular line intersects $L$ is the shortest distance between $p$ and any other point on the line $L$?
Now take the center of the circle, $O$, and draw the perpendicular (containing $O$) to the line in question, $L$,  and mark the point of intersection with the line as $P_L$.
If the distance between $O$ and $P_L$ is greater than the radius of the circle and as $O$ to $P_L$ is the shortest distance for the center of the circle to the line, all distances from $O$ to the line are greater than the radius and none are equal to the radius and there are no points of the line that are on the circle.  The line is exterior to the circle.
If the distance between $O$ and $P_L$ is equal to the radius than $P_L$ is on the circle.  As all other distance from $O$ to the line are larger, there are no other points of the line one the circle.  Thus $L$ is a tangent line.
If the distance between $O$ and $P_L$ is less than the radius then $P_L$ is on the interior of the circle and you've already concluded this means the line interects twice.  But even if we hadn't.... you can extend $OP_L$ to a point $Q$ so that $OQ=r$. And we construct a circle with radius $r$ (this is actually our existing circle) and it interesects the line at two points.

Very close to what was needed! For the case when the distance between $O$ and $P_L$ is less than the radius, is it possible to use an argument that if we prolong $OP_L$ to $OQ$, then points $O$ and $Q$ are in different half-planes with respect to line $L$? I'm not sure whether it is enough to say that it means more points of a circle are in that same half-plane too.

Now that I think about it, perhaps it's worth a try to just construct a tangent to a circle through point $Q$, and it will be parallel to $L$ because $OQ$ is perpendicular to both lines. If we also construct a line parallel to $L$ through point $O$, by comparing distances we can conclude that the line $L$ is between the tangent through $Q$ and parallel line through $O$. That means $L$ should intersect the circle at two points (below the tangent, above the diameter parallel to the tangent)
